# Git push -u origin master.Wrong with SSH

Tags: git

Recently I'm learning about Git.But something wrong with me,When I type some command.

```
$ git push -u origin master
ssh: connect to host gmail.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't what happend.I try my best to search something about it but noting useful.Please,I'm confused.

Comment: More general question: how did you set up your repository ?

Comment: I have closeed my firewall.I use Windows system.

Comment: What? `connect to host gmail.com port 22` ? Are you trying to push to gmail.com?

Comment: Can you please describe the problem precisely ? 
Did it work before ? If yes,  what did you change ?
Else, how did you set up /initiated your repository ?
Because like @MegaTron highlighted, the `gmail.com` adress looks suspicious...

Comment: You may have switched the `email` entry with the repo url entry...

Comment: Thanks guys.I'm so stupid.I type wrong gmail into this.sorry everyone and thank all of you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> ssh: connect to host gmail.com port 22: Connection timed out

As you can see from error message you try to push to **gmail.com**.

**gmail.com** - is not a git repository as we know, so you can't push.

To add remote repository use

```
git remote add <NAME> <PATH>
```

or to change URL:

```
git remote set-url <NAME> <PATH>
```

Comment: Thanks!I found it.I'm a new foolish guy.Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to have been of help